# why jQuery code replace last image with first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, slideshow

In this code everything works fine but at some point after moving slider right and left, images change position. First replace last image and that continues sometimes in a short time but sometimes slider work fine long time...I want to know what is the reason for this behavior?

```js
var lastBulletActive = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var triggers = $('ul.triggers li');
  var bull = $('ul.triggers li');
  var lastElem = triggers.length - 1;
  var target;
  triggers.first().addClass('active');
  $('#ud_load').animate({
    width: '100%'
  }, 5000);

  function sliderResponse(target) {
    triggers.removeClass('active').eq(target).addClass('active');
    $('#ud_load').stop().css({
      width: '0px'
    });
    $('#ud_load').animate({
      width: '100%'
    }, 5000);
  }

  triggers.click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
      target = $(this).index();
      sliderResponse(target);
      resetTiming();

    }
  });

  $('.left').click(function() {
    target = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
    lastElem = triggers.length - 1;
    target === 0 ? target = lastElem : target = target - 1;
    sliderResponse(target);
    moveLeft();
    lastBulletActive = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
    resetTiming();

  });

  $('.right').click(function() {
    target = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
    target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target + 1;
    sliderResponse(target);
    moveRight();
    lastBulletActive = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
    resetTiming();

  });

  $('#ud_slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#ud_slider ul');

  bull.click(function() {
    resetTiming();
    var curBulletActive = $(this).index();
    if (curBulletActive < lastBulletActive) {
      var toMove = lastBulletActive - curBulletActive;
      console.log(toMove + " left");
      for (i = 0; i < toMove; i++) {
        moveLeft(100);
      }
    } else if (curBulletActive > lastBulletActive) {
      var toMove = curBulletActive - lastBulletActive;
      console.log(toMove + " right");
      for (i = 0; i < toMove; i++) {
        moveRight(100);
      }
    }
    sliderResponse(curBulletActive);
    lastBulletActive = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();

  });


  defineSize();

  function sliderTiming() {
    target = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
    lastBulletActive = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
    target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target + 1;
    sliderResponse(target);
    moveRight();
  }

  var timingRun = setInterval(function() {
    sliderTiming();
  }, 5000);

  function resetTiming() {
    clearInterval(timingRun);
    timingRun = setInterval(function() {
      sliderTiming();
    }, 5000);
  }


  function moveLeft() {
    var slideWidth = $('#ud_slider ul li').width();
    $('#ud_slider ul').animate({
      left: +slideWidth
    }, 500, function() {
      $('#ud_slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#ud_slider ul');
      $('#ud_slider ul').css('left', '');
    });

  }

  function moveRight() {
    var slideWidth = $('#ud_slider ul li').width();
    $('#ud_slider ul').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 500, function() {
      $('#ud_slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#ud_slider ul');
      $('#ud_slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  }

});

$(window).on("resize", defineSize);

function defineSize() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();

  $('.ud_slide, #slider_container').css({
    width: windowWidth
  });
  var slideCount = $('#ud_slider ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#ud_slider ul li').width();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#ud_slider ul').css({
    width: sliderUlWidth,
    marginLeft: -slideWidth
  });

}
```

```css
body,
html,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#slider_container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#ud_slider {
  height: 640px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ud_slide {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 640px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#ud_slider ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
#ud_slider ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.ud_slider_1 {
  background-image: url('https://gameonsnacks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Adam-Diaz.jpg');
}
.ud_slider_2 {
  background-image: url('http://carolinealberoni.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/online-games.jpg');
}
.ud_slider_3 {
  background-image: url('https://watergamespc.weebly.com/uploads/3/0/1/9/30199027/5208331.jpg');
}
.ud_slider_4 {
  background-image: url('http://knowledgeoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/planetside_2_game-wide.jpg');
}
#ud_load {
  background: red;
  height: 5px;
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -128px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.left {
  left: 0;
}
.right {
  right: 0;
}
.triggers {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  width: 240px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -120px;
}
ul.triggers li.active {
  background-color: red;
}
ul.triggers li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Vjezbanje</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="slider_container">
    <div id="ud_slider">

      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="ud_slider_1 ud_slide">

          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="ud_slider_2 ud_slide">

          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="ud_slider_3 ud_slide">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="final">
          <div class="ud_slider_4 ud_slide">
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div id="ud_load"></div>
      <div class="button left">
        <img src="img\back.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="button right">
        <img src="img\front.png" />
      </div>

    </div>

    <ul class="triggers">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/funkcija3.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `bull` and `triggers` are both the same selector, is that correct?

Comment: `moveLeft` changes the order of the images when it does `$('#ud_slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#ud_slider ul');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sliderTiming() method, `lastBulletActive` should be calculated after you move the image:

```js
var lastBulletActive = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var triggers = $('ul.triggers li');
  var bull = $('ul.triggers li');
  var lastElem = triggers.length - 1;
  var target;
  triggers.first().addClass('active');
  $('#ud_load').animate({
    width: '100%'
  }, 5000);

  function sliderResponse(target) {
    triggers.removeClass('active').eq(target).addClass('active');
    $('#ud_load').stop().css({
      width: '0px'
    });
    $('#ud_load').animate({
      width: '100%'
    }, 5000);
  }

  triggers.click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
      target = $(this).index();
      sliderResponse(target);
      resetTiming();

    }
  });

  $('.left').click(function() {
    target = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
    lastElem = triggers.length - 1;
    target === 0 ? target = lastElem : target = target - 1;
    sliderResponse(target);
    moveLeft();
    lastBulletActive = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
    resetTiming();

  });

  $('.right').click(function() {
    target = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
    target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target + 1;
    sliderResponse(target);
    moveRight();
    lastBulletActive = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
    resetTiming();

  });

  $('#ud_slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#ud_slider ul');

  bull.click(function() {
    resetTiming();
    var curBulletActive = $(this).index();
    if (curBulletActive < lastBulletActive) {
      var toMove = lastBulletActive - curBulletActive;
      console.log(toMove + " left");
      for (i = 0; i < toMove; i++) {
        moveLeft(100);
      }
    } else if (curBulletActive > lastBulletActive) {
      var toMove = curBulletActive - lastBulletActive;
      console.log(toMove + " right");
      for (i = 0; i < toMove; i++) {
        moveRight(100);
      }
    }
    sliderResponse(curBulletActive);
    lastBulletActive = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();

  });


  defineSize();

  function sliderTiming() {
    target = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();    
    target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target + 1;
    sliderResponse(target);
    moveRight();
    lastBulletActive = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
  }

  var timingRun = setInterval(function() {
    sliderTiming();
  }, 5000);

  function resetTiming() {
    clearInterval(timingRun);
    timingRun = setInterval(function() {
      sliderTiming();
    }, 5000);
  }


  function moveLeft() {
    var slideWidth = $('#ud_slider ul li').width();
    $('#ud_slider ul').animate({
      left: +slideWidth
    }, 500, function() {
      $('#ud_slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#ud_slider ul');
      $('#ud_slider ul').css('left', '');
    });

  }

  function moveRight() {
    var slideWidth = $('#ud_slider ul li').width();
    $('#ud_slider ul').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 500, function() {
      $('#ud_slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#ud_slider ul');
      $('#ud_slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  }

});

$(window).on("resize", defineSize);

function defineSize() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();

  $('.ud_slide, #slider_container').css({
    width: windowWidth
  });
  var slideCount = $('#ud_slider ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#ud_slider ul li').width();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#ud_slider ul').css({
    width: sliderUlWidth,
    marginLeft: -slideWidth
  });

}
```

```css
body,
html,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#slider_container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#ud_slider {
  height: 640px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ud_slide {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 640px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#ud_slider ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
#ud_slider ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.ud_slider_1 {
  background-image: url('https://gameonsnacks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Adam-Diaz.jpg');
}
.ud_slider_2 {
  background-image: url('http://carolinealberoni.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/online-games.jpg');
}
.ud_slider_3 {
  background-image: url('https://watergamespc.weebly.com/uploads/3/0/1/9/30199027/5208331.jpg');
}
.ud_slider_4 {
  background-image: url('http://knowledgeoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/planetside_2_game-wide.jpg');
}
#ud_load {
  background: red;
  height: 5px;
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -128px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.left {
  left: 0;
}
.right {
  right: 0;
}
.triggers {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  width: 240px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -120px;
}
ul.triggers li.active {
  background-color: red;
}
ul.triggers li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Vjezbanje</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="slider_container">
    <div id="ud_slider">

      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="ud_slider_1 ud_slide">

          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="ud_slider_2 ud_slide">

          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="ud_slider_3 ud_slide">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="final">
          <div class="ud_slider_4 ud_slide">
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div id="ud_load"></div>
      <div class="button left">
        <img src="img\back.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="button right">
        <img src="img\front.png" />
      </div>

    </div>

    <ul class="triggers">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/funkcija3.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```